# 'The target account name is incorrect'-IOException with DirectoryInfo.GetFiles

Tags: c#, .net, ioexception, directoryinfo, mscorlib

I am doing this and this was working before:

```
var di = new DirectoryInfo("FolderOnSharedDrive");
var files = di.GetFiles("*");
```

I have now this exception and the only difference I can see is that I have now Windows 10.

```
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.IOException' in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: The target account name is incorrect.
```

Comment: It is a low-level Windows error, ERROR_WRONG_TARGET_NAME.  The machine that provides the share isn't happy about the user account you use.  That tends to happen when you update your OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by deregistering the machine completely from the network.

Answer (score 3):

Try to use the IP address instead of the computer name.